# Why the concurrent modification comes here

Tags: java, exception, linkedhashmap, concurrentmodification

The following code throws the concurrent modification exception

```
import java.util.*;

public class SampleTest
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("value1","a");
    map.put("value2","b");
    map.put("value3","c");
    map.put("value4","d");
    map.put("value5","e");

    // sublists
    List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> subList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        subList.add(map);
    }

    List<List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> mainList = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        mainList.add(subList);
    }

    List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> temp =  mainList.get(mainList.size() - 1);
    List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> temp2 =  mainList.get(mainList.size() - 2);
    for(LinkedHashMap<String,String> map2 : temp) {
        temp2.add(map); // Exception Thrown Here......
    }
}
}
```

However i fixed the code by creating a new List and add the map and finally add the new list outside the loop in temp2

```
example,
    List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> pp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(LinkedHashMap<String,String> map2 : temp) {
       pp.add(map);
    }
    temp2.addAll(pp);
```

I would like to know in detail why the concurrent happens in the earlier code.

Thanks.

Comment: You're adding the same list multiple times to `mainList` so `mainList.get(mainList.size() - 1)` and `mainList.get(mainList.size() - 2)` are returning the same instance. You then loop over `temp` while adding to `temp2` but again both variables are the same instance. The end result is you're iterating a list while modifying it at the same time.

Comment: @Slaw is correct. One fix is to use a different `ArrayList` for each index in `mainList` with the following: `mainList.add(new ArrayList<>(subList));`

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you guys please help me with more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
List<List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> mainList = new LinkedList<>();
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    mainList.add(subList);
}
```

Is adding `subList` three times to `mainList`. When I say "three times" I mean the code is literally adding **the same instance** three times. You could modify the element at any valid index of `mainList` and you'd be modifying all the other elements because they're the same instance. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value); it may help with this concept.

As a consequence, this code:

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> temp =  mainList.get(mainList.size() - 1);
List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> temp2 =  mainList.get(mainList.size() - 2);
```

Grabs the **same** `List` from two different indices and assigns it to two different variables. In other words, `temp == temp2` (reference equality) is `true`.

You then iterate the `List` using the `temp` variable while at the same time you are adding elements to the `List` using the `temp2` variable:

```
for(LinkedHashMap<String,String> map2 : temp) {
    temp2.add(map); // Exception Thrown Here......
}
```

But again, `temp` and `temp2` refer to the **same** `List`. Your code is basically doing the following:

```
List<Object> list = ...; // create new list and fill it
Object someObj = new Object();

for (Object obj : list) { // iterating list
    list.add(someObj); // modifying list while it's being iterated
}
```

---

End result is you're iterating the `List` while attempting to modify it at the same time. This is not allowed by `LinkedList` (or really any of the standard implementations of `Collection`). From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the Iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

If you aren't aware, the for-each loop internally uses an `Iterator` when the target of the loop is an `Iterable`.